# How can I add a text box dynamically under an other by pressing a button in c#? (winforms)

Tags: c#

[image]
*^^^Fixed Layout ^^^*

[image]
The image is a reconstruction in Excel (I don't have the code at hand right now)

Question 1: How can I add a text box under an other dynamically (the yellow text boxes for reference) by pressing the 'Add Ingredient' button?

Question 2: Can I use a simpler method instead of adding text boxes? (a type of cell/row code)

Comment: Check out DataGridView

Comment: @WayneScicluna check out `<ItemTemplate>` in DataGridView.. there are a lot of examples on the web for this here is a link to help get you started
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4a173a0f-1453-4e51-a29d-e5b4226f4679/dynamically-add-gridview-columns-and-buttons?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: Please always indicate the platform you are targeting: WPF, ASP, Winforms..!

Answer (score 3):

Why don´t you use a table or a listview to display the ingredients?
Its more flexible to display...

For example:

1. Add "ListView"-Control to your form
2. Change the view of your listview to "Details" to display the list as a table
3. Add 4 Columns to your ListView (id, name, quantity, price)
4. Create a struct to hold your data (id, name, ...)
5. Add a generic List of your struct (like "List list = new List()") (class instance variable)
6. Add Items to the List ("list.AddItem([...])")
7. Bind the List as  datasource.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

So I managed to get it done using the dataGridView.

```
   public void AddItemToTable()
    {
        int idOfItem;
        string[] details = ItemCombo.Text.Split(','); //ItemCombo = combo box
        idOfItem = int.Parse(details[0]);

        int n = dataGrid.Rows.Add();
        dataGrid.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = Vars.itemName[idOfItem];
        dataGrid.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = InputValueBox.Text + " " + Vars.itemScale[idOfItem];
        dataGrid.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = "€" + ((Vars.itemPrice[idOfItem] / Vars.itemBundle[idOfItem]) * double.Parse(InputValueBox.Text)).ToString("F4");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ListView and then do an Insert or Add.  How to get columns?  Add a listView, then when in "Main_Load", add the following code:

```
void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     listView.View = View.Details;
     listView.Columns.Add("Ingredients", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
     listView.Columns.Add("Amount", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
     listView.Columns.Add("Cost", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
}

void _btnAddIngredients(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
     listView.Items.Add("Add Text Here");
}
```